# mysql set seed for rand

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, random, seed

Is it possible to set the seed for the RAND() function in MySQL?
I need this for unit testing, to make sure I know what the expected outcome will be.

In PHP one would simply do:

```
<?php srand(12345); echo rand(); ?>
```

In my model I currently have a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Now in my unit test I want to make sure I know what the seed for RAND() is so I know which record the query returns.

Maybe by performing an extra query before the query in my model?

I know I can just supply add an argument to RAND(), but this is not what I want; I do not want to modify the query.

PS. I am using Linux; will it help to set the seed for /dev/random maybe?

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to this: [MySQL RAND with with parameter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

The `RAND` function support a parameter `RAND(N)` which will be used as a seed.

Comment: I know, but then I have to modify the query which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we don't unit test a SQL function, we unit test our code that calls the SQL function.

So perhaps rather than testing for a specific return value, just test that you get *some* value. If the query is returning a value, you know it is "working" and you remain insulated from the inner technicals of MySQL. You also don't have to modify your query.

Comment: Yes I think I have to go with this. So there is no way to set the seed?

Comment: Only as a parameter, as suggested by @Plamen Nikolov.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the seed in one query does not affect subsequent calls to RAND().

Answer (score 0):

To add to this discussion, I think it is useful to do limited unit testing on database queries, procedures and functions too as this is part of the business logic.

One way how to get have a deterministic `rand` is to use `now()` as the seed in `rand`. And `now()` can be set by the test case in the database session like this:

```
SET timestamp=UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2022-01-01 11:38:01')
```

subsequent calls to `RAND(NOW())` will now always have the same result.

Note that the trick above is very useful for any queries as well in which you want to mock a time